# Can I set an onChange event using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I want to have all input elements on my page trigger a function when they change.  Can I do it from a CSS?

I tried this:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
   input {onChange: function() {alert("foo");};}
</STYLE>
```

It didn't work in Google Chrome.

Comment: What does CSS have to do with JavaScript and DOM events?

Comment: to me, thats blasphemy! CSS is for styles my friend, not logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS doesn't provide eventing.  If this is what you want, then I would write a JavaScript function that runs when the page loads.  In the function, traverse the form elements for everything that has the tagName `input`.  For each of those, add an event handler.

Comment: … but is not :hover, :focus, :blur considered events? Guess one could say it is a state, and :change would be a "pure event"? Within DOM these are defined as events. In CSS they are "User Action Pseudo-classes". So perhaps; "CSS does not provide eventing" is a bit off? (I'm merely thinking out loud here.)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't that is against the very nature of CSS. The only thing close are Pseudo-Classes like :focus :hover ect, but even they only allow to apply a different Style. So no, you can't just write JS in a CSS File and call it CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. About the error in google chrome, use onblur. refer to the following post for more info:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5480bd096a668f1e&hl=en